# how to hold variable value the same after method usage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = x;
y.fill(5);
console.log(x); //[5,5,5]
console.log(y); //[5,5,5]
```

how to prevent *var x* array to be changed by *fill()* method? Why *y.fill()* change both *var y* and *var x*?

Comment: You may have two variables, but you only have one array.

Answer (score 3):

`y` is pointing to the same array as `x`. If you want to prevent that, you need to copy/clone `x`, and assign that to `y`.

```
var y = x.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

your var y is a reference to the x array. try it with `var y = [1,2,3];`. `var y = x.slice();` will get you a shallow copy. Look up deep VS. shallow copies to determine if this is an appropriate solution.